# react css style syntax - set value of css prop with variables and text in one line

Tags: css, reactjs

I have this code:

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    paddingLeft: 0,
    paddingRight: 0,
  }
});
```

Is it posible to set padding with only one line?
(I want to do something like this:)

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: 0 theme.spacing.unit * 3',
  }
});
```

Comment: yes, you can, try `padding: theme.spacing.unit*3  0,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by creating the string like so (using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)):

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 3} 0`,
  }
});
```

If the theme spacing unit was `10px` that would result in `padding: 10px 0`, which is shorthand for `padding: 10px 0 10px 0;`

It is important to use the back ticks (`) and not quotes.

One thing to note, if your `theme.spacing.unit` does not include the unit of measure, add it after the curly braces like so:

```
padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px 0`,
```

Comment: Thank you. I've forgot about "px"))) 
The last variant works perfectly.